# Show that $d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|$ defines a metric on $H^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The exercise says that the "Hilbert cube" $H^\infty$ is the collection of all real sequences $x = (x_{n})$ with $|x_n| \le 1$ for $n = 1,2,...$ 
I know you have to check the 4 properties for being a metric space, I think I can figure out the first 3 but how do I proof the triangle inequality?

Comment: It follows from the triangle inequality for $|\cdot|$.  For all $n$, we have $|x_n - y_n| \le |x_n| + |y_n|$.  Since the series converges absolutely, we can rearrange to get what we want.

Comment: @XanderHenderson How do I know the series converges absolutely?

Comment: By definition $|x_n|,|y_n| \le 1$ for all $n$.  From this, it follows that $|x_n - y_n| \le |x_n| + |y_n| \le 2$.  But then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}|x_n-y_n| \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\cdot 2$, which is geometric, and converges by the geometric series test.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot Xander.